# Admob mediation + Millenial Media interstitials.How to?

Tags: android, admob, ads, interstitial

know somebody how to use adMob mediation to manage MMedia's interstitials?

I actually use 1) adMob Floor 2)MMedia (ID banner ad) 3)admob "standar".

Ideas?

Thanks in advance, and soyrry for "the post"; my english is too bad to explain.

[SOLVED]
· "adview" at layout with the "Old Ad-ID" (Banner)
· Create other ad-id (Type Interstitials)
· Setup mediation, add Interstitial ID from MMedia
· Integrate interstitials id on code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are already using Admob to mediate between MillennialMedia and Admob.

When using Admob to mediate you should create an AdUnit for banner and a second AdUnit for interstitial (if you are also serving interstitial).

Then include the MM banner ad in your banner mediation chain, and the MM interstitial in your interstitial mediation chain.

Comment: Yes.But the question is...admob has only "1 place for 1 ad-ID" and MMedia has 1 ID pro banner + 1 ID pro Inters